# What are questions to ask during oncampus visit?

Tags: job, tenure-track

During the campus visit, I meet the faculty members, dean and provost individually and they asks me if I have questions to them. Actually, since I got all answers from the chair, I reply "no, I donot have questions". My question is what should I ask the dean, and provost, and other faculty members?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What questions should I ask as a candidate during an interview for a tenure-track assistant professor position?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/33011/what-questions-should-i-ask-as-a-candidate-during-an-interview-for-a-tenure-trac)